# Jquery DataTables Object Not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I've been beginners on jquery... and I download this but lack of tutorials... If someone know how to do this correctly... please help me... it's hard to figure out cause when I google there is no questions/help like object on DataTables... really need help someone if can..

The output of alert is correct... 
this is the output of my alert...
[image]

and this is my code below on script:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'api/mstStudent',
        data: "",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function (rows) {
            //alert(JSON.stringify(rows, null, 1));
            var oTable = $('#example').dataTable({
                "bProcessing": true,
                "sAjaxSource": JSON.stringify(rows, null, 1),
                "aoColumns": [
                    { "mData": "ID" },
                    { "mData": "StudentID" },
                    { "mData": "StudentName" },
                    { "mData": "Course" },
                    { "mData": "YearLevel" },
                    { "mData": "Religion" },
                    { "mData": "Gender" },
                    { "mData": "isLock" }
                ]
            });
        }
    });
});
```

the object is Student and inside it is...

```
StudentID
StudentName
Course
YearLevel
Religion
Gender
isLock
```

**EDIT:**

this is the output when I use `document.write(JSON.stringify(rows, null, 1));` I just shorten it...

```
[
{ 
    "ID": 1,
    "StudentID": "101",
    "StudentName": "Jerald Patalinghug",
    "Course": "BSIT",
    "YearLevel": "1",
    "Religion": "Catholic",
    "Gender": "Male",
    "isLock": true 
}, 
{ 
    "ID": 12,
    "StudentID": "102", 
    "StudentName": "David Laude", 
    "Course": "BSIT", 
    "YearLevel": "3", 
    "Religion": "Catholic", 
    "Gender": "Female", 
    "isLock": true 
}
]
```

**EDIT 2**

and my controller... I don't know how to add `aaData` on front...

```
private Data.DataClasses1DataContext db = new Data.DataClasses1DataContext();

    // GET api/<controller>
    public List<Models.mstStudent> Get()
    {
        var Students = from s in db.mstStudents
                       select new Models.mstStudent
                       {
                        ID = s.ID,
                        StudentID = s.StudentID,
                        StudentName = s.StudentName,
                        Course = s.Course,
                        YearLevel = s.YearLevel,
                        Religion = s.Religion,
                        Gender = s.Gender,
                        isLock = s.isLock
                       };
        return Students.ToList();
    }
```

Comment: I'm not really familiar with datatables, but I don't think you are using sAjaxSource correctly. I think that is supposed to be a URL that will return a JSON object (so the datatable creation would not be inside an ajax call; I think the Datatables plugin handles that for you)

Answer (score 0):

Your `json data` should be contained by a `aaData variable` like,

```
{
  "aaData": [
     {
       "ID": "1",
       "StudentID": "101",
       "StudentName": "David",
       "version": "BSIT",
       "YearLevel": "2",
       "Religion": "Catholic",
       "Gender": "Male",
       "isLock": "true",
     },
     ....// more record objects
   ]
}
```

See [Docs](http://datatables.net/release-datatables/examples/ajax/objects.html)

Comment: I try this `var source1 = '{ "aaData":' + JSON.stringify(rows, null, 1) + ' }';` then I change this `"sAjaxSource": source1,` but still not working..

Comment: It works when I copy the output of `document.write(source1);` then I paste it on the `objects.txt` then change the `"sAjaxSource":'objects.txt'`... IDK how to do this... without creating .txt